# Sorting a Range Column in DB2 stored as a String

Tags: sql, db2

I have a VARCHAR column VALUE in DB2 which has values similar to this below,

```
10-30 
2000-3000
1750-2000
1250-1500
30-50
50-100
100-300
```

When I query the table `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY VALUE`, I am getting something like

```
10-30
100-300
1250-1500
1750-2000
2000-3000
30-50
50-100
```

Is there way I can come up with a query to sort it as below

```
10-30
30-50
50-100
100-300
1250-1500
1750-2000
2000-3000
```

Comment: ... _generally_, databases shouldn't be storing delimited columns (there's a few exceptions in some reporting scenarios).  This is part of the reason why.  If you can, split into two columns.  Even better, potentially make the (hopefully exclusive) upper bound derived/computed, based on the next row (you'll have to do something about the gaps).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(VALUE, 1, INSTR(VALUE, '-') - 1) AS INT)
```

Comment: Thanks JuSun Lee. For it to work in DB2 I tweaked it a bit to get the result.

SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(VALUE,LOCATE('-', VALUE') - 1) AS INT)

Comment: You might want to explain what this code does and how it solves the problem. Code only answers are rarely helpful to future visitors.